# Enable DjangoTemplates syntax highlighting in PyCharm 2016

Tags: django, intellij-idea, pycharm

I work in PyCharm 2016.1 Community Edition.

Here is some official reference related: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/debugging-django-templates.html

But it has no connection to 2016 version. Settings are different.
How to enable Django templates syntax highlighting, if i work with ***.html** files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyCharm Community Edition does not support Django](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). You'll get need to get the Pro version.